# Android block change TextView value every 100ms

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView `minutesValue`

and listener for this :

```
 minutesView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public String oldMinutesText;

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                String currentText = s.toString();
                boolean b = !currentText.equals(oldMinutesText);
                if (b) {
                    oldMinutesText = currentText;
                    mSoundPlayer.playClickSound(); // Play more times than expected.
                }
            }
        });
```

I have a logic when i set a value to TextView every 1-10ms.

setMinutes **0** 
setMinutes **0**
setMinutes **0**
setMinutes **20** // here i pass new value
setMinutes **0**  // pass new value again in 10ms
setMinutes **0**

So i take a next effect - textview will not repaint, but logic works. TextView displayed **0** but real value is **20**, and because values changes so fast i think the TextView doesn't be in time repaint so fast. In example above i need to play sound when textview really changed the meaning and redraw.

I want to allow set, a new value every 100ms (block repaint ms<100). How i can do that?

Answer (score 0):

What's the loop that's calling setMinutes look like? If it's something like:

```
setMinutes(20);
sleep(100);
setMinutes(0);
```

The UI thread isn't going to have a chance to do the redraw.

Comment: setMinutes called related to touchPosition. I want a skip mechanism which allow set a value every 100ms.